# Extjs 3.4 combobox keep value format after selection

Tags: extjs, combobox

Using Extjs 3.4 I have a combobox with a tpl config:

```
var myCombo= new Ext.form.ComboBox(
    {
            typeAhead: true,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            store: myStore,
            valueField: 'value',
            displayField: 'desc',
            tpl: '<tpl for="."><div class="x-combo-list-item">{value} - {desc}</div></tpl>'
    });
```

When I click in the combo the `value - decription` string is correctly shown. But when I select a `value - description` the combobox only show me the `valueField`.

Is possible to keep the tpl format after selecting a row from combobox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jcgarcia is right in the fact that you cannot have a custom template for the way the text is rendered within the TriggerField element. The only thing you can do is specify the JSON attribute that will be displayed by setting `displayField` to something...

You are left with 2 options:

1/ use the events like jcgarcia proposed.

2/ a simpler solution is that the server can send a new attribute with the info to display.

**currently the server returned this data in the store:**

```
[{value:1, desc:'a'}, {value:2, desc:'b'}, ...]

// selecting a value would only display 'a'
```

**have the server return this instead to the store:**

```
[{value:1, desc:'a', displayed:'1 - a'}, {value:2, desc:'b', displayed:'2 - b'},...]
```

then change

```
displayField: 'desc',
```

to

```
displayField: 'displayed',
```

This means that you might be passing some data twice and you will be rendering part of a view within the server side so it's not ideal. But it's easy to implement and the trade off might be worth it.

Cheers

Comment: Easy and good idea to implement it with ExtJS **3.4.0** components ;)

Answer (score 1):

Is not possible on ExtJS 3.4.0 version..

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-cfg-tpl

But you can use `beforeselect` event or `change` event to modify manually...

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-event-beforeselect
http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.form.ComboBox-event-change

On **ExtJS 4.1.1** you can try using the following:

```
var myCombo= new Ext.form.ComboBox(
    {
            typeAhead: true,
            triggerAction: 'all',
            store: myStore,
            valueField: 'value',
            displayField: 'desc',
            // Template for the dropdown menu.
            tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', '<tpl for=".">', '<div class="x-boundlist-item">{value} - {desc}</div>', '</tpl>'),
            // template for the content inside text field
            displayTpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', '<tpl for=".">', '{value} - {desc}', '</tpl>')
    });
```

Here's some example

http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/docs/Ext.form.field.ComboBox.2/viewer.html

Best Regards,